# If $\lim{a_nb_n} = \infty$ and $0<a_n<1\quad \forall n$, then prove or disprove that $\lim b_n=\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I really tried to find an answer to this one and wrapped my head around it with lots of proving methods (BW theorem, by definition...), but didn't manage to do so evantually...

Suppose $\lim a_nb_n=\infty$, and $\forall n, 0<a_n<1$. 
Then, I must either prove or disprove that $\lim b_n=\infty$. I believe this is true, since I couldn't find any counter-example. Is my intuition correct? what would be the most efficiant way to prove this?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\lim a_n b_n = \infty$
We have $\forall A >0 \in \mathbb{R}, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n >N, a_nb_n>A$
And since $0<a_n<1$ we have (at least for $n > N$ where the terms are positive): $b_n > a_n b_n$
So that $\forall A >0 \in \mathbb{R}, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n >N, b_n>A$
Which by definition means $\lim b_n = \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly it's impossible if $(b_n)$ is bounded, so assume $(b_n)$ is unbounded. If $(b_n)$ is not divergent to infinity, then there exists $M$ such that $b_n \le M$ for infinitely many $n$, so $a_nb_n < M$ for infinitely many $n$, contradicting divergence of $(a_nb_n)$ to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Proof:

Let $M > 0$. Because $a_n b_n\to\infty$, there is a $n_0$ such that $a_n b_n > M$ for all $n> n_0$. Because $0 < a_n < 1$ it follows that also $b_n >M$ for all $n > n_0$. This proves $b_n\to\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$a_n b_n < b_n \implies \liminf a_nb_n\leq \liminf b_n \implies \infty \leq \liminf b_n. $